# Find time zone and time from given string of timestamp

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I need to parse a timestamp and get both the time and the timezone from a string like the following,

Timestamp = "2013-09-17T14:55:00.355-08:00"

From the above string, I should be able to get time as 2:55pm and timezone as EST (Eastern)

Can anyone please let me know how the above parsing can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a `DateTimeOffset` which contains both the local time and the offset from UTC, using `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`. However, there may be multiple time zones observing the same offset from UTC at that time, so you can't get the actual time zone.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        string text = "2013-09-17T14:55:00.355-08:00";
        DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(text,
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffzzz",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dto);
    }
}
```

Or using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        string text = "2013-09-17T14:55:00.355-08:00";
        // Use GeneralIsoPattern just to get a default culture/template value
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTimePattern.GeneralIsoPattern
            .WithPatternText("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffo<+HH:mm>")
            .Parse(text)
            .Value;
        Console.WriteLine(odt);
    }
}
```